# ArrayList<Integer> addAll method not adding

Tags: java, eclipse, collections, arraylist

Im trying to add the contents of this.array to a temp array but when i print the return value its always empty.

Class object

```
import java.util.*;
public class LetterInventory{

private ArrayList<Integer> array;
private int size;

public LetterInventory(String input){
    size = input.length();
    array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i = 0;i<input.length();i++){
        array.add(i,(int)input.charAt(i));
    }
}

public LetterInventory(){
    size = 0;
    array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
}

public int size(){
    return size;
}

public LetterInventory add(LetterInventory other){
    LetterInventory temp = new LetterInventory();
    temp.array.addAll(array);
    return temp;
}

public String toString(){
    String result = "[";
    for(int i = 0;i<=size-1;i++){
        int temp = array.get(i);
        result += (char)temp;
    }
    return result += "]";
}
}
```

and my Client  code

```
import java.util.*;

public class Practice {
public static void main (String[] args){
    LetterInventory l1 = new LetterInventory("aaa");
    LetterInventory l2 = new LetterInventory("bbb");
    System.out.println(l1);
    System.out.println(l2);
    LetterInventory sum = l1.add(l2);
    System.out.println(sum);
}

}
```

And the output is always [ ] no matter what i do. I despretly need help on this. As i've spent the vast majority of this day trying to fix this issue.

Comment: There are quite a few issues in your code, but the primary reason you are seeing blank output is due to your `toString()` implementation. It uses `size` for iterating, which will be 0 when you call `add()` method.

Comment: in addition, your add() method does nothing with the contents of *other*. It completely ignores the passed-in variable.

Comment: @Kylar The unused parameter is due to this being just a slimed down version, the full program is much longer then this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `toString()` method's for loop have the issue. You haven't set the value to `size` variable other than 0 in no argument Constructor, so it won't execute the for loop

```
public String toString(){
    String result = "[";
    for(int i = 0;i<=size-1;i++){
        int temp = array.get(i);
        result += (char)temp;
    }
    return result += "]";
}
```

Change the `add()` method like below

```
public LetterInventory add(LetterInventory other){
    LetterInventory temp = new LetterInventory();
    temp.array.addAll(array);
    temp.size = temp.array.size();
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: a newly initialised ArrayList has length of zero. the code above sets size to zero

Answer (score 3):

You are tracking `size` separately from the actual size of the list. This is OK in your constructor, but your `add` method copies the list, but doesn't set size. Try not using a size variable and use `array.size()` which will always be correct.

*ps. there is another bug in your add method as noted by Kylar above*

Answer (score 0):

You `toString()` method uses the member `size` to iterate over array elements. But when you add you are not updating the `size`.

My suggestion would be to remove the `size` member variable and use `array.size()` instead

Answer (score 0):

```
public LetterInventory add(LetterInventory other){
    LetterInventory temp = new LetterInventory();       
    temp.array.addAll(this.array);
    temp.array.addAll(other.array);
    temp.size = this.size + other.size;
    return temp;
}
```

this is the answer

Comment: SlipperySeal's answer is very apt. Much better to use list.size() rather than calculate it every time.

Comment: thank you Anirudh. i did get a little annoyed it wasn't marked as correct :)